# If remove WHERE from code it works other time it does not

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_GET['open'])){
    $sub_id = $_GET['open'];
    $sub_query = "SELECT * FROM `forum_sub` WHERE s_id = $sub_id";
    $sub_run  = mysqli_query($connection, $sub_query); 
    $sub_row  = mysqli_fetch_array($sub_run);
    $sub_name = $sub_row['title']; 
    }

/*** 
 * Error starts here: 
 ***/
$topic_query = "SELECT * FROM `forum_topic` WHERE categories = $sub_name";
$topic_run = mysqli_query($connection, $topic_query);

/***  
 * Note also here:
 ***/
 while($topic_row = mysqli_fetch_array($topic_run)){ 
       $p_id = $topic_row['id'];
       $p_title = $topic_row['subject'];
       $p_msg =$topic_row['msg'];
       $p_date = $topic_row['date'];
       $p_username = $topic_row['u_name'];
       $p_view = $topic_row['view'];
      }
```

When I Remove WHERE then it is okay otherwise it gives error

Please help me

I tried every way but it just not happening. if I remove WHERE tag then it is happening properly

[forum_topic structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmE9b.jpg)

Comment: Which where clause? the first or the second?

Comment: 1. Do you have a `categories` field in the `forum_topic` table? 2. **Please learn about [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)!** 3. Why use `SELECT *` when you only really need `title` from the first query? 4. You would be much better to use [`JOIN`](http://www.sql-join.com/)

Comment: second one having . forum_topic

Comment: yeah I have and that categories of forum_topic is equall to $sub_name = $sub_row['title']; of forum_sub

Comment: Please post the error you are having. You're missing a } to close the while loop in your code.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

no i have closed it properly please look little down

Comment: Can you post your forum_topic structure?

Comment: hello sir please look find it in question area .i have uploaded it

Comment: why do you have `**` in your code? comment blocks are `/*` ... `*/`

Comment: it is to showing you the special areas

Comment: Ok, I've updated your code so it shows up better now.

Comment: still not solved :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this

```
$sub_query = "SELECT * FROM `forum_sub` WHERE s_id =". $sub_id;
```

Comment: actually  i can fetch data from that table but unable from forum_topics

Comment: you are doing same mistake in the forum_topics

Comment: $topic_query = "SELECT * FROM `forum_sub` WHERE categories =". $sub_name;


It is also giving same result

Comment: did you change in the forum_topics as well?

Comment: yes sir. I have changed in for both the table. forum_sub is perfectly running but forum_topic is not

Answer (score -1):

Your variables placed inside of the if statement are undefined when outside of the if statement.

Try

```
if(isset($_GET['open'])){
$sub_id = $_GET['open'];
$sub_query = "SELECT * FROM `forum_sub` WHERE s_id = $sub_id";
$sub_run  = mysqli_query($connection, $sub_query); 
$sub_row  = mysqli_fetch_array($sub_run);
$sub_name = $sub_row['title']; 

   $topic_query = "SELECT * FROM `forum_topic` WHERE categories = $sub_name";
   $topic_run = mysqli_query($connection, $topic_query);

   while($topic_row = mysqli_fetch_array($topic_run)){
   $p_id = $topic_row['id'];
   $p_title = $topic_row['subject'];
   $p_msg =$topic_row['msg'];
   $p_date = $topic_row['date'];
   $p_username = $topic_row['u_name'];
   $p_view = $topic_row['view'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir i have tried this but it is also not happening :(

Comment: Is it reporting any errors?

Comment: same error mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: Are you sure you're copying the code correctly as I'm trying the same code and there aren't any errors? Double check the curly braces are in the right place.

Comment: i am sorry to say it sir but i'm having same error

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code please? thanks.

Comment: Which code you gave i updated..still not happening.. i m very sad and i will leave this profession .

Comment: I'm very sorry you're frustrated but as I mentioned, I have replicated the error only when the variables are being called outside of the if statement. When called from inside the if statement, there aren't any errors on my side.

Comment: Is that error occurs from table structure?

Comment: No it occurs because your referencing variables which are defined inside the if statement. Place the entire code in the if statement to make it work.

Comment: Sir as u said i habe done but same result.and before that same kind of coding i have done successfully but this time i cant do this..i am bad and very bad man in this world